# setting particular date to Date object

Tags: android, date-comparison, android-date

I've been trying this from a long time.
I'm having today's date and I want to compare it with specific date.

But when I set **particular** date like this, it gives me wrong output:

```
    Calendar cal;
    SimpleDateFormat dateformatter;
    String currentdate;
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    dateformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    //Getting today's date
    currentdate = dateformatter.format(cal.getTime());
    Log.i(Class_Tag, "current = " + currentdate);

    //Setting specific date
    Date start = cal.getTime();
    cal.set(2012, 06, 20);
    Date end = cal.getTime();
    Log.i(Class_Tag, "end = " + dateformatter.format(end));

    long diff = end.getDate() - start.getDate();
    Log.i(Class_Tag, "diff : " + diff);

    long diff1 = end.getMonth() - start.getMonth();
    Log.i(Class_Tag, "diff mnth : " + diff1);

    long diff2 = end.getYear() - start.getYear();
    Log.i(Class_Tag, "diff yr : " + diff2);

    if (start.compareTo(end) == 0) {
        Log.i(Class_Tag, "EQUAL");
    } else if (start.compareTo(end) < 0) {
        Log.i(Class_Tag, "end b4 start, delete");
    } else {
        Log.i(Class_Tag, "start b4 end, do nothing");
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
current = 2012-06-20
end = 2012-07-20 ////WHY it is showing month as '7' when I've set it to '6'?
diff : 0
diff mnth : 1 //Because of the wrong month in end date, this comes 1 instead of 0
diff yr : 0
end b4 start, delete //this also is not correct
```

I've tried several solutions, but no gains.

My only objective is to get whether that particular date **has passed** today's date or not.

Any help appreciated.

---

### Edit

in the following code snippet,

```
//Setting specific date
    Date start = cal.getTime();
    cal.set(2012, 06, 20);
    Date end = cal.getTime();
```

If I set `cal.set(2012, 06, 20);` to `cal.set(2012, 05, 20);`, the month diff. comes out to 0.

This implies that `month` in particular date is getting incremented by '1', *but* ***WHY***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, 
A month is represented by an integer from 0 to 11; 0 is January, 1 is February, and so forth; thus 11 is December.

You can check read more about [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) here and more about [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

**Update:**

One more thing about **getMonth()** => Its deprecated, instead `Calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)`, check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getMonth%28%29).

Comment: Ok, that was the whole hoopla about. It's from 0-11 rather than 1-12. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

long dateNowMillis = cal.getTimeInMillis();

cal.set(2013, 1, 23);

long specDate = cal.getTimeInMillis();

if(dateNowMillis > specDate)
{
    System.out.println("Passed");
}
else if(dateNowMillis == specDate)
{
    System.out.println("Now");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Not passed");
}
```